# Stack text in CAD based on what it contains and coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

Please see the attached image showing how I need to stack text in CAD. Everything I've tried has failed to account for all situations.

Basically, I am using the coordinate of the text to try and determine how to arrange it properly. Any help would appreciated. My work is below:

```
       private void swaptext()
    {
        using (ac.AcadDocumentLock)
        {
            using (var t = ac.StartTransaction)
            {
                try
                {                        
                    MText tx1 = (MText)ids[0].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    MText tx2 = (MText)ids[1].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    string conts1 = tx1.Contents;
                    string conts2 = tx2.Contents;

                    Point3d pos1 = tx1.Location;
                    Point3d pos2 = tx2.Location;

                    if ((tx1.Contents.Contains("TWO")) && (pos1.X < pos2.X))
                    {
                            tx1.Contents = conts2;
                            tx2.Contents = conts1;
                    }

                    else if ((tx1.Contents.Contains("TWO")) && (pos1.Y < pos2.Y))
                    {

                            tx2.Contents = conts1;
                            tx1.Contents = conts2;
                    }


                    ids.Clear();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                 ac.AcadDocument.Editor.WriteMessage("Error: ==>\n{0}\nTrace: ==>\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                }
                t.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

[Stacking Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTlK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just rotate the text back to 0 degrees, then you can just compare which text has higher Y coordinate. And that one should contain the word "ONE"

```
private void swaptext()
    {
        using (ac.AcadDocumentLock)
        {
            using (var t = ac.StartTransaction)
            {
                try
                {
                    MText tx1 = (MText)ids[0].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    MText tx2 = (MText)ids[1].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    string conts1 = tx1.Contents;
                    string conts2 = tx2.Contents;
                    Extents3d Ex1 = tx1.GeometricExtents;
                    Extents3d Ex2 = tx2.GeometricExtents;
                    Point3d pos1 = Ex1.MaxPoint.RotateBy(-tx1.Rotation, tx1.Normal, tx1.Location);
                    Point3d pos2 = Ex2.MaxPoint.RotateBy(-tx2.Rotation, tx2.Normal, tx2.Location);

                    if ((tx1.Contents.Contains("TWO")) && (pos1.Y > pos2.Y))
                    {
                        tx1.Contents = conts2;
                        tx2.Contents = conts1;
                    }
                    else
                        if ((tx2.Contents.Contains("TWO")) && (pos2.Y > pos1.Y))
                        {
                            tx1.Contents = conts2;
                            tx2.Contents = conts1;
                        }

                    ids.Clear();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    ac.AcadDocument.Editor.WriteMessage("Error: ==>\n{0}\nTrace: ==>\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                }
                t.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Genius always makes things seem so simple XD. Thank you